# Choose Stylesheet on Browser's side or on Server's side?

Tags: javascript, browser, stylesheet

my problem is that I have to use different stylesheets for different browsers and I have to choose between 2 methods:

1. Choose with javascript on browser's side
2. Choose on server's side based on HTTP request.

Which is better and why?

(It is a university project not a public site)

Answer (score 2):

In favor of client side: You can serve static pages instead of having to run a script, so it's less server overhead.

In favor of server side: Will work if the user has Javascript disabled.

Comment: I can't really imagine anyone with javascript disabled in this day and age...  Although I guess there are some security/privacy paranoid people these days.

Comment: Do people disable javascript on their browsers? Why?

Comment: I don't know, but some people still advocate writing pages that degrade gracefully if JS is disabled. I personally don't lose sleep over it. It was just the only thing I could think of in favor of server-side.